# Is something wrong with this series of assignments?

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to cause a series of LEDs to grow steadily brighter over the course of about 30 seconds using an FPGA. However, my code is currently causing them to blink steadily for that duration. Running a Vivado simulation, I've found where the problem is occurring. The code in question is:

```
logic [32:0] intro_count = 33'd0;
logic [32:0] BRIGHTNESS = 33'd0;

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    intro_count <= intro_count +1;
    BRIGHTNESS <= (intro_count * 33'd64)/33'd6150000000;
end
```

Rather than counting up slowly as it is intended to, the BRIGHTNESS value is flipping from 0 to 1 and back again. Is something wrong with this assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with 33 bit values, which can hold a maximum value of 2<sup>33</sup> - 1 = 8589934591. You're dividing by 6150000000. Therefore the largest possible quotient you can ever get is 1 (since the divisor is more than half the largest representable value). You probably expected the intermediate calculation to automatically promote to a higher bit size to arrive at the desired result, but this is not the case.

One option could be to reduce the "fraction" (multiplier and divisor) so as not to overflow. Or you can explicitly promote the intermediate to a higher width, but this is less elegant and it's not guaranteed the synthesis will optimize it in the best way. Is the exact value 6150000000 crucial? You could get much simpler synthesis with a "nicer" number, like a power of 2 or sum of small number of powers of 2.

You could also just run a counter, and increment the brightness when the counter reaches 6150000000. This requires an additional register but that's not likely to be an issue, and this is by far the more common approach I see when simple bit shifting doesn't do the job.